# I would like to code a slider with jquery from scratches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Hy everybody,

My task is to realize a slider with pure HTML / Jquery code.

The template is the follow

[image: My Slider]

and the html code for the upper template is the follow

```
<div id="viewport-container">
    <section id="sliding-container">
        <article id="slide-0" class="slide"><span></span></article>
        <article id="slide-1" class="slide"><span></span></article>
        <article id="slide-2" class="slide"><span></span></article>
        <article id="slide-3" class="displayed-slide"><span></span></article>
    </section>
</div>
<nav id="slider-nav">
    <a href="#slide-0" class="active"></a>
    <a href="#slide-1"></a>
    <a href="#slide-2"></a>
    <a href="#slide-3"></a>
</nav>
```

We start with button {#slide-0} which display article {ID="slide-0"}; when we select another button, let's say {#slide-3} then article with {ID="slide-0"} fade out and article with {ID="slide-3} fade in; when we select another button, let's say {#slide-1} then article with {ID="slide-3"} fade out and article with {ID="slide-1} fade in; and so on.

I started to struggle with this aim a week ago and so I ask your precius help.

Many many thanks

Comment: sorry but where are you stuck? What is your question?

Comment: Well the slider pips `index` relates to the slide `index`, so you should start from there....

Comment: Show us some code working of your jquery slider where you got error. Here you are asking us to do the work for you. Since you are new, please note that we can help you if u get stuck at something but not code it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it (phew!!)

Now this is the css

```
#viewport-container {
height: 250px;
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#sliding-container {
width: 100%;
}

#slide-0 {
background-image: url(/Images/slide_home.jpg);
height: 250px;
width: 980px;
position: absolute;
}

#slide-1 {
background-image: url(/Images/slide_informatica.jpg);
height: 250px;
width: 980px;
position: absolute;
}

#slide-2 {
background-image: url(/Images/slide_musica.jpg);
height: 250px;
width: 980px;
position: absolute;
}

#slide-3 {
background-image: url(/Images/slide_recensioni.jpg);
height: 250px;
width: 980px;
position: absolute;
}

#slider-nav {
text-align: center;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#slider-nav a {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
display: inline-block;
background: #ddd;
border-radius: 50%;
}

#slider-nav a.active {
background: #999;
}
```

this is the html

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="CSS/Slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="viewport-container">
<section id="sliding-container">
<article id="slide-0" class="displayed" style="display:block;"><span></span></article>
<article id="slide-1" style="display:none"><span></span></article>
<article id="slide-2" style="display:none"><span></span></article>
<article id="slide-3" style="display:none"><span></span></article>
</section>
</div>
<nav id="slider-nav">
<a id="btn-0" href="#slide-0" class="active"></a>
<a id="btn-1" href="#slide-1"></a>
<a id="btn-2" href="#slide-2"></a>
<a id="btn-3" href="#slide-3"></a>
</nav>
```

and this is the script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var $navButtons = $("#slider-nav > a");

$navButtons.click(
function () {
var $selectedButton = $(this);
var rawIdSlideToFadeIn = $selectedButton.attr("href");

$navButtons.removeClass("active");
$selectedButton.addClass("active");

crossFading(rawIdSlideToFadeIn);
});

function crossFading(rawIdSlideToFadeIn) {
var $slideToFadeIn = $(rawIdSlideToFadeIn);                
var $slideToFadeOut = $("article.displayed");
var idSlideToFadeIn = $slideToFadeIn.attr("id");
var idSlideToFadeOut = $slideToFadeOut.attr("id");                

if(idSlideToFadeIn != idSlideToFadeOut)
{
$slideToFadeOut.removeClass("displayed").css("style", "none").fadeOut();
$slideToFadeIn.addClass("displayed").css("style", "block").fadeIn();
}
}
});
</script>
```

Yes, some part of this code has to be improved, but the kernel is built,

Special thanks to SushiBalboha: his hint showed me the right way.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This will get you going.
You will need:
    - http://jquery.com/ - JQuery
    - http://jqueryui.com/ -JQueryUI

With these two your work is easy.
First reference JQuery in your website then you reference JQueryUI.

Then you will do something like this in your own JQuery Code:

The HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="firstSlide">
        <img class="active" src="pics/home/1.1.gif"/>
        <img src="pics/home/1.2.gif"/>
        <img src="pics/home/1.3.gif"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    #slider
    {
        position: relative;
        height: 180px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid black;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    }

    #firstSlide
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 198px;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #firstSlide img
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #firstSlide img.active
    {
        z-index: 3;
    }
```

The JQuery:

```
var howLongEffectLasts = 1000;
var timerInterval = 7000;
var slideDelay = 300;
var slideEffect = 'slide';
var slideDirection = 'up';

var timer = setInterval('DoIt1()', timerInterval);

function DoIt1()
{
    var $active = $('#firstSlide' + ' .' + 'active');
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#firstSlide' + ' ' + 'img:first');
    $next.css('z-index',2);
    $active.toggle(slideEffect, { direction: slideDirection }, howLongEffectLasts, function() {
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
    });
    setTimeout(function() { DoIt1(); }, slideDelay);
}
```

In the JQuery, just change the var's to your needs. Also, change the CSS etc to your own needs. The Z-INDEXes are VERY important here - so be careful when you change theCSS I gave you.

Comment: Pleasure. This will allow you different types of slides. Namely: Fade, Explode, Blind, Pop, Bounce, Shake... yeah there's quite a few.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a javascript function in your href that can just change the class of your article.

When you change the class of your article, you can display them or not (like we can see, class=slide or displayed-slide)

I don't know if it's what you want to do ?

Have you try some things ?